# Best way to modifying multiple win controls in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, forms

I want to learn about threading in windows form application for C#. Currently I trying to a create program which has two counters that increments independent of each other. The current value of the two counters are to be stored in two separate labels.

What would be the best procedure to obtaining this feat? I was thinking of having the threads somehow communicate back to the main UI thread to update the labels but I don't know if that would be feasible or if there is a better solution out there.

Comment: How do the counters increment? A button press, the seconds tick by....?

Comment: One way would be to raise events when the numbers change, and have the GUI subscribe to those events.

Comment: A button press would start the counters for both of the labels. The counter is created using a for loop with thread.sleep(500)

Comment: Reticulated Spline, in using that method would both of the counters have equal time to update the GUI or would one eventually take over the other?